# ¿Como puedo sacar el contenido de un ArrayList<String> y meterlos en un constructor?

Tags: java, arraylist

Buenas noches, mi pregunta es como puedo sacar los datos que contiene un ArrayList y al sacarlo los pueda insertar en un constructor parametrizado de 4 parametros que son String, String, String, int?. La clase es Revista con esos 4 parametros, y dentro del ArrayList tengo los datos que los he sacado de un fichero, pues cuando tengo los datos en el arrayList lo que quiero que cada 4 posiciones del array cree una nueva Revista con sus datos pasándolo por parametros, pero siempre solamente me saca uno.
Este es mi codigo:`

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PruebaLeerFicheroNuevo {
    private static File fichero = new File("./fichero");
    private static FileReader fr;
    private static BufferedReader br;
    private static ArrayList<Publicacion> publicaciones = new ArrayList<Publicacion>();
    public static Publicacion nueva Publicacion;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(fichero);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String palabra;
        ArrayList<String> centinela = new ArrayList<String>();

        while ((palabra = br.readLine()) != null) {
            centinela.add(palabra);

        }

        // System.out.println("DATOS DE CENTINELA: " + centinela.toString());

        ArrayList<Publicacion> mo = new ArrayList<Publicacion>();

        for (int i = 4; i < centinela.size(); i++) {
            String nombre = centinela.get(0);
            String autor = centinela.get(1);
            String materia = centinela.get(2);
            int numero = Integer.parseInt(centinela.get(3));
            nuevaPublicacion = new Revista(nombre, autor, materia, numero);
            publicaciones.add(nuevaPublicacion);
        }

        br.close();

        // MOSTRAMOS LOS DATOS DE publicaciones

        for (int i = 0; i < publicaciones.size(); i++) {
            Publicacion ver = publicaciones.get(i);
            if (ver instanceof Revista) {
                System.out.println("DATOS ver: ");
                System.out.println(ver.toString());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}
`

Comment: ¿Qué error te presenta? Me refiero más específicamente, qué resultado da, y cuál resultado buscás (Sí, entiendo que pasas 4 argumentos y así creas un objeto, pero si puedes proveer aunque sea un ejemplo de la información que posees y el **resultado** que obtienes con ese código, podría ayudar un poco :)

Comment: ¿has pensado en hacer un arrayList<Revista>? Con un objeto Revista, con atributos String, String, String, Int? luego podrías acceder haciendo centinela.get(indice).getString1();  por ejemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solución corta

```
 for (int i = 0; i < centinela.size() -4; i+=4) {
        String nombre = centinela.get(i);
        String autor = centinela.get(i+1);
        String materia = centinela.get(i+2);
        int numero = Integer.parseInt(centinela.get(i+3));
        nuevaPublicacion = new Revista(nombre, autor, materia, numero);
        publicaciones.add(nuevaPublicacion);
    }
```

---

#### Me explico

Uno de los errores que cometes es que estas inicializando la variable `i` en 4, por lo que el for comienza a iterar a partir de la posición 4 de la lista y desde hay el valor de `i` va incrementando 1, por lo que ese `for` funciona de la siguiente manera (literal): [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]... hasta llegar al final de la lista.

Otro error que cometes es que en todas las iteraciones del `for` obtienes los mismos valores de la lista, eso es porque al método `get` de la lista le estas pasando posiciones estáticas: [0, 1, 2, 3], por lo que en todas las iteraciones obtienes los valores que se encuentran en esas posiciones de la lista. Para recorrer la lista tienes que utilizar el valor de `i`, que es el que va aumentando en cada iteracion del ciclo: `centinela.get(i)`.

Para lograr lo que quieres tienes que recorrer la lista de 4 en 4 y en cada iteracion obtener los valores de cuatro posiciones de la lista, eso lo haces con `i`, para obtener el valor de la posición 1 de la lista utiliza `i`, para obtener el valor de la segunda posición de la lista utilizas `i+1` y así con todas las posiciones que quieras obtener de la lista en cada iteracion. Si lo haces de esa manera en la primera iteracion obtendrás los valores almacenados en las posiciones [0, 1, 2, 3]; en la segunda [4, 5, 6, 7]...

Ten en cuenta que al recorrer la lista de cuatro en cuatro, tienes que restarle cuatro al tamaño de la lista, para que en la ultima iteracion no se produzca la excepción `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Esto es porque el valor de `i` aumenta cuatro en cada iteracion y en cada iteracion obtienes 4 valores de lista, tomando como ejemplo una lista de 12 posiciones, en la primera iteracion el valor de `i` es 0 y recorres las posiciones [0, 1, 2, 3], en la segunda es 4 [4, 5, 6, 7], en la tercera 8 [8, 9, 10, 11] y en la cuarta es 12, pero en la penultima iteración ya recorres las ultimas posiciones de la lista y si sigues iterando recorrerás posiciones que no existen, lo cual causara la excepción.

Comment: Muchas gracias, al final lo he conseguido, gracias por tu consejo. Pero para que me funcione he tenido que quitar en el for (int i = 0; i < centinela.size() -4; i+=4)  el -4, y con ello ya me lo ha cogido. Sobre tu comentario si, se los errores, porque estoy con un proyecto y antes de meterlo en el proyecto creo otro nuevo y pruebo las cosas antes de hacerlo, y cuando funciona lo inserto en el proyecto. MUCHAS GRACIAS A TODOS!!